# SQL Error: ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns. I have no idea what's going on

Tags: sql, oracle, key

Here is my code:

```
create table PROGRAMS
(PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PROGNAME));

CREATE TABLE COMMITTEE_MEMBER
(CMNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
Q1 NVARCHAR2 (22),
Q2 NVARCHAR2 (21),
Q3 NVARCHAR2 (21),
Q4 NVARCHAR2 (21),
PRIMARY KEY (CMNAME, PROGNAME),
FOREIGN KEY (PROGNAME)
REFERENCES PROGRAMS
ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE DONATION_TYPE
(PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
Q1 NVARCHAR2 (21),
Q2 NVARCHAR2 (21),
Q3 NVARCHAR2 (21),
Q4 NVARCHAR2 (21),
PRIMARY KEY (PROGNAME));

CREATE TABLE LOCATED_AT
(PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
CAMPNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PROGNAME, CAMPNAME),
FOREIGN KEY (PROGNAME)
REFERENCES PROGRAMS
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (CAMPNAME)
REFERENCES CAMPUS 
ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE CAMPUS 
(CAMPNAME NVARCHAR2 (14) NOT NULL, 
 Q1 NVARCHAR2 (21),
 Q2 NVARCHAR2 (21),
 Q3 NVARCHAR2 (21),
 Q4 NVARCHAR2 (21),
 PRIMARY KEY (CAMPNAME));

CREATE TABLE DONOR 
(DONNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
PROJECT NVARCHAR2 (15), 
PRIMARY KEY (DONNAME, PROGNAME),
FOREIGN KEY (PROGNAME)
REFERENCES PROGRAMS
ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE CONTRIBUTION 
(CMNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
PROGNAME NVARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
DONNAME NVARCHAR2 (22) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT NVARCHAR2 (8) NOT NULL,
DATE_ NVARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CMNAME, PROGNAME, DONNAME, AMOUNT, DATE_),
**FOREIGN KEY (CMNAME)** 
REFERENCES COMMITTEE_MEMBER 
ON DELETE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (PROGNAME)
REFERENCES PROGRAMS
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (DONNAME)
REFERENCES DONOR
ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

The bolded is where it is giving me an error message. I have no idea what's going on. Please help.

Comment: I don't use Oracle but `FOREIGN KEY (CMNAME) REFERENCES COMMITTEE_MEMBER` wouldn't pass in T-SQL. `FOREIGN KEY (CMNAME) REFERENCES COMMITTEE_MEMBER (CMNAME)` (assuming `CMNAME` is a column on `COMMITTEE_MEMBER`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `committee_member` table has a composite primary key on `(CMNAME, PROGNAME)`.  The foreign key in `contribution` would, likewise, need to reference the composite key not just one of the two columns that are part of the primary key.  Assuming that you intend the `PROGNAME` column in `CONTRIBUTION` to be part of the foreign key, you can do something like

```
FOREIGN KEY( CMNAME, PROGNAME )
  REFERENCES committee_member(CMNAME, PROGNAME)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Personally, I would always specify the column names in the parent table that you are referencing because that can only improve clarity.  When you allow composite keys, it becomes even more important because it is too easy to inadvertently list the columns in the child table in a different order than the keys were listed in the primary key which will lead to foreign key violation errors that are non-trivial to debug.

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for editing my initial message as well, friend.